# Ensuring that static variables don't get reset

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am making a simple ASP.NET MVC application that is used for maintenance/batch processes on a database. It is not a traditional web app where there are many users each with session ids, etc. Only one user is expected to use the app at a time. Therefore, I am relying on public static variables in several places.

Is there a way to guarantee that public static variables are not reset at any given time? I am declaring the classes that the variables are in as static classes, and moving these classes to a folder outside App_Code. This does not seem like enough, as it seems on occasion that the static variables are being reset. Is there a way to guarantee that they are not reset?

Comment: you should never rely on that - use constants, session state, or a transactional database.

Comment: there is no way to avoid this. This is why databases are used to persist data. your static variables will be reset everytime the app pool recycles or becomes idle. there is really no avoidance here.

Comment: No. Some sort of permanent persistence medium (database, file system, etc) is the only way.

Comment: Are you under the impression that the "static" keyword in C# means "not changeable"?  I might be misunderstanding, but it sounds more like you're looking for either a const or readonly.  Additionally, you potentially could set your properties to only have a getter against a private var, no setter, which will in effect make it "unchangeable" I would think.

Comment: I ended up using session state instead of modifiable static variables.  There were some places I was using global modifiable static variables for convenience, but it looks like that's a bad idea.

Comment: The static variables may be reset when the whole appdomain is reloaded during IIS process recycling, you'd be better off saving the static variables to persistent storage and reloading them in their static constructor or Global.asax. Now, if you start using a database like this, why not use completely? (removing static altogether).

Comment: If it at all you want to use static even after above comments,you will need to use lock around then , if they are set once, then use static readonly